# Downloadable product is not working- data is not inserting in database

Tags: downloadable

in my setup somehow downloadable product is not working. If I checkout with downloadable product I got everything as usual but when go to my profile it's always showing "**You have not purchased any downloadable products yet.**". I was trying to debug this and found that table "**downloadable_link_purchased**" and "**downloadable_link_purchased_item**" are always empty. So database insert for downloadable products is not working. **Downloadable**  is a core module, so I'm confused here. I also log the **$orderItem** variable from **saveDownloadableOrderItem** method in **code\core\Mage\Downloadable\Model\observer.php** . I got something like this

```
(
    [store_id] => 1
    [quote_item_id] => 498280
    [product_id] => 953
    [product_type] => downloadable
    [product (Mage_Catalog_Model_Product)] => Array
        (
            [entity_id] => 953
            [entity_type_id] => 4
            [attribute_set_id] => 4
            [type_id] => downloadable
            [sku] => sfasfase2434
            [created_at] => 2015-08-26 05:59:42
            [updated_at] => 2015-08-26 05:59:42
            [has_options] => 0
            [required_options] => 0
            [name] => downloadable
            [small_image] => no_selection
            [thumbnail] => no_selection
            [url_key] => dfdfd
            [url_path] => dfdfd
            [links_title] => Links
            [msrp_enabled] => 2
            [msrp_display_actual_price_type] => 4
            [status] => 1
            [visibility] => 4
            [tax_class_id] => 2
            [enable_googlecheckout] => 0
            [links_purchased_separately] => 0
            [price] => 10.0000
            [is_salable] => 1
            [stock_item (Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item)] => Array
                (
                    [item_id] => 943
                    [product_id] => 953
                    [stock_id] => 1
                    [qty] => 71.0000
                    [min_qty] => 0.0000
                    [use_config_min_qty] => 1
                    [is_qty_decimal] => 0
                    [backorders] => 0
                    [use_config_backorders] => 1
                    [min_sale_qty] => 1.0000
                    [use_config_min_sale_qty] => 1
                    [max_sale_qty] => 0.0000
                    [use_config_max_sale_qty] => 1
                    [is_in_stock] => 1
                    [low_stock_date] => 2015-08-27 09:52:02
                    [use_config_notify_stock_qty] => 1
                    [manage_stock] => 0
                    [use_config_manage_stock] => 1
                    [stock_status_changed_auto] => 0
                    [stock_status_changed_automatically] => 0
                    [use_config_qty_increments] => 1
                    [qty_increments] => 0.0000
                    [use_config_enable_qty_inc] => 1
                    [use_config_enable_qty_increments] => 1
                    [enable_qty_increments] => 0
                    [is_decimal_divided] => 0
                    [type_id] => downloadable
                    [stock_status] => 1
                    [product_name] => downloadable
                    [store_id] => 1
                    [product_type_id] => downloadable
                    [product_status_changed] => 1
                    [ordered_items] => 8
                )

            [request_path] => dfdfd
            [tier_price] => Array
                (
                )

            [is_in_stock] => 1
            [store_id] => 1
            [customer_group_id] => 1
            [group_price] => Array
                (
                )

            [group_price_changed] => 0
        )

    [base_original_price] => 10
    [product_options] => a:3:{s:15:"info_buyRequest";a:3:{s:4:"uenc";s:48:"aHR0cDovL2Rldi5qZWZmZHVuaGFtLmNvbS9zaG9wL2RmZGZk";s:7:"product";s:3:"953";s:3:"qty";i:1;}s:15:"is_downloadable";b:1;s:17:"real_product_type";s:12:"downloadable";}
    [sku] => sfasfase2434
    [name] => downloadable
    [is_qty_decimal] => 0
    [qty_ordered] => 8
    [is_virtual] => 1
    [original_price] => 10
    [applied_rule_ids] => 
    [price] => 10
    [base_price] => 10
    [tax_percent] => 0
    [tax_amount] => 0
    [row_weight] => 0.0000
    [row_total] => 80
    [base_tax_amount] => 0
    [base_row_total] => 80
    [is_nominal] => 0
    [price_incl_tax] => 10
    [base_price_incl_tax] => 10
    [row_total_incl_tax] => 80
    [base_row_total_incl_tax] => 80
    [weee_tax_applied] => a:0:{}
    [weee_tax_applied_amount] => 0
    [weee_tax_applied_row_amount] => 0
    [base_weee_tax_applied_amount] => 0
    [base_weee_tax_applied_row_amount] => 0
    [base_weee_tax_applied_row_amnt] => 0
    [weee_tax_disposition] => 0
    [base_weee_tax_disposition] => 0
    [weee_tax_row_disposition] => 0
    [base_weee_tax_row_disposition] => 0
    [discount_percent] => 0
    [discount_amount] => 0
    [base_discount_amount] => 0
    [gift_message_available] => 0
    [order_id] => 71269
    [created_at] => 2015-08-27 10:45:23
    [updated_at] => 2015-08-27 10:45:23
    [item_id] => 141388
)
```

Then I install a fresh magento and log that object where downloadable product is working fine. I got here

```
(
    [store_id] => 1
    [quote_item_id] => 13
    [product_id] => 2
    [product_type] => downloadable
    [product (Mage_Catalog_Model_Product)] => Array
        (
            [entity_id] => 2
            [entity_type_id] => 4
            [attribute_set_id] => 4
            [type_id] => downloadable
            [sku] => shjhsjh124356
            [has_options] => 1
            [required_options] => 0
            [created_at] => 2015-08-26 05:32:34
            [updated_at] => 2015-08-26 05:32:34
            [name] => test downloadable
            [small_image] => no_selection
            [thumbnail] => no_selection
            [url_key] => testdownloadable
            [url_path] => testdownloadable.html
            [msrp_enabled] => 2
            [msrp_display_actual_price_type] => 4
            [links_title] => Links
            [status] => 1
            [visibility] => 4
            [tax_class_id] => 2
            [links_purchased_separately] => 0
            [price] => 20.0000
            [is_salable] => 1
            [stock_item (Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item)] => Array
                (
                    [item_id] => 2
                    [product_id] => 2
                    [stock_id] => 1
                    [qty] => 83.0000
                    [min_qty] => 0.0000
                    [use_config_min_qty] => 1
                    [is_qty_decimal] => 0
                    [backorders] => 0
                    [use_config_backorders] => 1
                    [min_sale_qty] => 1.0000
                    [use_config_min_sale_qty] => 1
                    [max_sale_qty] => 0.0000
                    [use_config_max_sale_qty] => 1
                    [is_in_stock] => 1
                    [use_config_notify_stock_qty] => 1
                    [manage_stock] => 0
                    [use_config_manage_stock] => 1
                    [stock_status_changed_auto] => 1
                    [stock_status_changed_automatically] => 1
                    [use_config_qty_increments] => 1
                    [qty_increments] => 0.0000
                    [use_config_enable_qty_inc] => 1
                    [use_config_enable_qty_increments] => 1
                    [enable_qty_increments] => 0
                    [is_decimal_divided] => 0
                    [type_id] => downloadable
                    [stock_status] => 1
                    [product_name] => test downloadable
                    [store_id] => 1
                    [product_type_id] => downloadable
                    [product_status_changed] => 1
                    [ordered_items] => 3
                )

            [do_not_use_category_id] => 1
            [request_path] => testdownloadable.html
            [tier_price] => Array
                (
                )

            [is_in_stock] => 1
            [store_id] => 1
            [customer_group_id] => 1
            [group_price] => Array
                (
                )

            [group_price_changed] => 0
            [downloadable_links] => Array
                (
                    [1 (Mage_Downloadable_Model_Link)] => Array
                        (
                            [link_id] => 1
                            [product_id] => 2
                            [sort_order] => 0
                            [number_of_downloads] => 5
                            [is_shareable] => 0
                            [link_url] => http://xxxxxxxx.com/xyz/pit.mp4
                            [link_type] => url
                            [default_title] => test me 
                            [title] => test me 
                            [default_price] => 0.0000
                            [price] => 0.0000
                            [product (Mage_Catalog_Model_Product)] => *** RECURSION ***
                        )

                )

        )

    [base_original_price] => 20
    [product_options] => a:4:{s:15:"info_buyRequest";a:5:{s:4:"uenc";s:76:"aHR0cDovL21hZ2VudG8uZGV2OjgwMDAvaW5kZXgucGhwL3Rlc3Rkb3dubG9hZGFibGUuaHRtbA,,";s:7:"product";s:1:"2";s:8:"form_key";s:16:"D5BIkM8ExafTYXH6";s:15:"related_product";s:0:"";s:3:"qty";s:1:"1";}s:5:"links";a:1:{i:0;s:1:"1";}s:15:"is_downloadable";b:1;s:17:"real_product_type";s:12:"downloadable";}
    [sku] => shjhsjh124356
    [name] => test downloadable
    [is_qty_decimal] => 0
    [qty_ordered] => 3
    [is_virtual] => 1
    [original_price] => 20
    [applied_rule_ids] => 
    [price] => 20
    [base_price] => 20
    [tax_percent] => 8.375
    [tax_amount] => 5.03
    [row_weight] => 0.0000
    [row_total] => 60
    [base_tax_amount] => 5.03
    [base_row_total] => 60
    [hidden_tax_amount] => 0
    [base_hidden_tax_amount] => 0
    [is_nominal] => 0
    [price_incl_tax] => 21.68
    [base_price_incl_tax] => 21.68
    [row_total_incl_tax] => 65.03
    [base_row_total_incl_tax] => 65.03
    [weee_tax_applied] => a:0:{}
    [weee_tax_applied_amount] => 0
    [weee_tax_applied_row_amount] => 0
    [base_weee_tax_applied_amount] => 0
    [base_weee_tax_applied_row_amount] => 0
    [base_weee_tax_applied_row_amnt] => 0
    [weee_tax_disposition] => 0
    [base_weee_tax_disposition] => 0
    [weee_tax_row_disposition] => 0
    [base_weee_tax_row_disposition] => 0
    [discount_percent] => 0
    [discount_amount] => 0
    [base_discount_amount] => 0
    [order_id] => 22
    [created_at] => 2015-08-27 10:35:39
    [updated_at] => 2015-08-27 10:35:39
    [item_id] => 22
)
```

So, in my view, within my faulty system the following section is missing ...

```
  [downloadable_links] => Array
                (
                    [1 (Mage_Downloadable_Model_Link)] => Array
                        (
                            [link_id] => 1
                            [product_id] => 2
                            [sort_order] => 0
                            [number_of_downloads] => 5
                            [is_shareable] => 0
                            [link_url] => http://xxxxxxx.com/xyz/pit.mp4
                            [link_type] => url
                            [default_title] => test me 
                            [title] => test me 
                            [default_price] => 0.0000
                            [price] => 0.0000
                            [product (Mage_Catalog_Model_Product)] => *** RECURSION ***
                        )

                )

        )
```

What can be the problem here ?

Comment: Are you sure that you set up the downloadable product in exactly the same way in both systems? Can you share a screenshot of the admin panel where you specified the downloadable links?

Comment: I think so, [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ubv5ajn1v525xq8/Screen%20Shot%202015-08-28%20at%201.22.55%20PM.png?dl=0) is the screenshot .